# Exchange 2010 SP1 Search Mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I am trying to search mailboxes (after doing an export to PST) and delete messages that meet a certain criteria.

Everytime I try and run the Search-Mailbox command, I get the following output:

```
The target mailbox or .pst file path is required.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 79CD2AE3
```

I've even tried the examples that PowerShell shows and still get the same message.

An example of trying a command out:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Search-Mailbox -Identity "David Tester" -SearchQuery "Subject:'Your bank statement'"
The target mailbox or .pst file path is required.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 79CD2AE3

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Could you please display your entire search-mailbox line so I can be more help?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to have some target mailbox and folder, or else the DeleteContent flag.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "April Stewart" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Your bank statement"' -TargetMailbox "administrator" -TargetFolder "SearchAndDeleteLog" -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

The example above is a Log Only search that won't move any messages.

See the manual page for the Search-Mailbox command and note which switches are required.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173.aspx